# rails Activeadmin update nestedrecord with parent record field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model (Perro Camada) with a nested attributes (perro).
In my active admin file "perro_camada.rb" i want to overwrite the birthday (nacimiento) in nested fields with birthday (nacimiento)  of parent record.

I don't have in troubles with the others fields like "padre_id" but with "nacimiento" dont work.

whats mi problem?

```
ActiveAdmin.register PerroCamada do
  menu parent: '☰ Perros', label: 'Camadas', priority: 2

  permit_params :nombre, :descripcion,  :orden, :imagen, :raza_id, :padre_id, :madre_id, :nacimiento, :portada, perros_attributes: [:id, :nacimiento, :perro_camada_id,  :perro_categoria_id,  :madre_id, :padre_id, :sexo, :vendido,  :precio, :nombre, :descripcion, :informacion, :precio,  :orden, :_destroy ]


  filter :nombre

   form do |f|
     f.inputs do
      f.input :nombre
      f.input :raza,              label: 'Raza',  :collection => PerroCategoria.all.map{|x|[x.nombre,x.id]}, include_blank: false 
      f.input :descripcion
      f.input :imagen, as: :file, :hint => image_tag(f.object.imagen.url(:thumb)), include_blank: false
      f.input :padre,  label: 'Padre',  :collection => Perro.Macho.all.map{|x|[x.nombre,x.id]}, include_blank: false 
      f.input :madre,  label: 'Madre',  :collection => Perro.Hembra.all.map{|x|[x.nombre,x.id]}, include_blank: false 
      f.input :nacimiento
      f.input :orden

      f.has_many :perros, heading: 'Perros' , allow_destroy: true, display: :panel do |k|
       k.input :nacimiento, :input_html => { value: f.object.nacimiento }
       k.input :padre_id,   :input_html => { value: f.object.padre_id, hidden: true }, as: :hidden
       k.input :madre_id,   :input_html => { value: f.object.madre_id, hidden: true }, as: :hidden
       k.input :perro_categoria_id, :input_html => { value:  f.object.raza_id, hidden: true }, as: :hidden
       k.input :nombre
       k.input :sexo, as: :select, collection:   Perro.sexos.keys, include_blank: false 
       k.input :precio
       k.input :vendido, as: :select, collection: Perro.vendidos.keys, include_blank: false 
       k.input :descripcion, :input_html => { value: f.object.nacimiento }
       k.input :informacion, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'mini'} }
      end
     end
     f.actions
  end
```

Comment: at least I change the values in the model, in a after_save rutine change the values